# JS file not loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to install slick slider on my website and I am getting this error saying that my local js.js file is not being loaded. The JS file is in the same directory as the the header so I am not sure what is causing this issue.
Below is a link of the error on devtools.
http://prntscr.com/kdle0y

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum- scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slickcarousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: Is the js file in the same directory as the page that is linking it?

Comment: Yeah, all the files are in the same directory.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Could you please edit your question to include the code?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Try renaming your js file to something completely different, such as test.js

Is your php spitting out any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Is that file containing the head "included" in a PHP file? I'm pretty sure that yes.

Then, the relative path to consider is from the page that includes that `<head>`.

Or try `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/from/domain_root/to/js.js"></script>` which **must** work. It begins with a front slash `/`.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the src to `./js.js`  Maybe that will help. Make sure the js.js file is in the same directory as the file, you are importing the script into.